# Jquery Mobile Page buttons don't work after page refresh

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

My jquery mobile app has a footer navigation that doesn't work after the page refresh happens - an example is here :

http://m-staging.qpme.com/quickpay-login.php#sessions-page

login:  stack@yahoo.com
password: stack

Then in the browser, refresh the page, then the bottom navigation does not work. I have tried a few different things, I have read, but no luck. Can anyone help?

Comment: Everything is working for me in chrome.

Comment: Working on iPad 2 latest update.

Comment: Once you login - goto http://m-staging.qpme.com/quickpay-login.php#sessions-page  and hit Refresh - then click on the account button. it will turn green but nothing will happen.

Comment: ok change `$('#sessions-page').page();` with `$('#sessions-page').trigger('create);` or `$('#sessions-page').trigger('pagecreate);` because this page is created dynamically you get the buttons not working on refresh.

Comment: The page is actually not generated dynamically - I went ahead and made the change - and it didn't fix it:

Comment: On a side note - the http://m.qpme.dev/quickpay-login.php#account-information page you can refresh on and the bottom navigation still works.. not sure what causes it not to work on all the other pages

Comment: it'll happen with any page you refresh. if you have Chrome or Firfox Firebug, login and then check elements. In `<head>` you'll find this `<base href="http://m-staging.qpme.com/login">` if you refresh any page, the `<base>` will be changed to the new refreshed page i.e. `<base href="http://m-staging.qpme.com/sessions-page">` if sessions-page is refreshed. how to fix this? Add `<base>` in `<head>` i.e. `<base href="http://m-staging.qpme.com/login">`.

Comment: This still did not fix it omar - very weird. Its something to do with the button and refreshing the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I jsut avoided the refresh by going to the desired page and using the jquery refresh code to repopulate the divs.

```
$("div").page();
```